# How to modify wp_query in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

i am working with wordpress,And i want to pass one parameter name "post_title" in wp_query,So i can change query and can get correct data,But my query is not changed(not displaying as i expected),I tried with following code

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'user',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
     'post_title' => $_GET['post_title'],
    'post_status' => [ 'publish']
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

when i print my $query->request then i getting following query

```
[request] = "SELECT   MZAGsQVeposts.* FROM MZAGsQVeposts  WHERE 1=1  AND MZAGsQVeposts.post_type = 'user' AND ((MZAGsQVeposts.post_status = 'publish')) ORDER BY MZAGsQVeposts.post_date DESC";
```

But expected query is

```
"SELECT   MZAGsQVeposts.* FROM MZAGsQVeposts  WHERE 1=1  AND MZAGsQVeposts.post_type = 'user' AND ((MZAGsQVeposts.post_status = 'publish')) AND MZAGsQVeposts.post_title='Lisa I' ORDER BY MZAGsQVeposts.post_date DESC";
```

Where i am wrong ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Doesn't seem like there is an argument for searching by title using WP_Query: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't query posts by title in wp_query, it's not a recognised argument. (See [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) for more info) however you can use [get_page_by_title](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_by_title/) and pass the title that way and it'll return the post object with that title.

Comment: okay then can i get "Post Data" ?

Comment: Yep, if you do `$user_obj = get_page_by_title( $_GET['post_title'], OBJECT, 'user');` you should get the post data in a variable.

Comment: can i pass multiple parameters with "post_title" so i can get data with multiple filters ( city,type,gender) ?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are asking. Are you able to give me an example? My initial feeling is no though.

Comment: let me explain , Actually now i am getting data by "post title" but now i want to get "city , gender , type " data as well , so for this i want to pass parameters so i can get correct data with filters which i pass, hope you understand my point

Comment: So in this instance are we saying that post title refers to a person, and from that person you want to get their gender and city etc?

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: Ah, OK, sure. Using get_page_by_title (and WP_Query) won't get use those details by default. Instead you would get the post ID and then use get_post_meta to get those details.